# Last Python version miss updated libraries, how to deal with this?

Tags: python, couchbase

Yesterday I updated Python on a PC from 3.5.1 to the latest version: 3.6.
I've done the same on a notebook, from 3.5.2 to 3.6.
It is natural to update Python from time to time.

I want to use Couchbase.
The LATEST SDK for Python is for the 3.4 version!
(couchbase-2.1.3.win-amd64-py3.4.exe)

Furthermore that library could be bugged because "pip install couchbase" returns this error (on 2 different machines).

```
    building 'couchbase._libcouchbase' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1
-I..\lcb-winbuild\x86\deps\include "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python36-32\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python36-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\exceptions.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\exceptions.obj
    exceptions.c
    c:\users\alex\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-h_bixmeo\couchbase\src\pycbc.h(25): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ---------------------------------------- Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\alex\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-h_bixmeo\\couchbase\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-tkag3cnx-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h_bixmeo\couchbase\
```

... and the Python SDK on GitHub (https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client) is marked [build|failing].

It is not the first time I have a too new version of Python but there is not an updated version of the library X yet.

**How you deal with this?

There is a workaround to this "general" problem?**
I mean a way to install the library "X" for Python 3.4 on a system with Python 3.5/3.6.

Alessandro

[Update]
The previous error (missing 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h') is due to the missing Couchbase C SDK.
The Python SDK depends from the C SDK.
Furthermore the Python SDK cannot be installed by pip:

> Note that installation by means of pip will not work on Windows.

Instead on the PyPi page and on GitHub it is not mentioned any problem and both suggest to use:
`pip install git+git://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client`

Also the C SDK is not installable with pip on Windows. :-(
The documentation says that you can download the binary version for your environment and

> the C SDK does not have any preferred installation path, and it is up
>   to you to determine where to place libcouchbase.dll.

1) The link for the latest version (2.7.0) for Visual Studio 2015 on Win x64 is broken. I have to use an older version or the Visual Studio 2012 version.
2) I don't know WHERE to unzip this SDK. There are NO instruction at all for this. I have not found any post/example on Google for install Python DSDK on Windows).

The `pip install` create a new temp folder under C:\users(current user)\AppData\Local\Temp(pip-khfdskhfsdk-build) so I don't know how to indicate where is the libcouchbase.h file (or the path of the C SDK).

I tried to build the SDK from sources using:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace 
    --library-dir d:\Downloads\libcouchbase-2.7.0_amd64_vc11\libcouchbase-2.7.0_amd64_vc11\lib  
    --include-dir d:\Downloads\libcouchbase-2.7.0_amd64_vc11\libcouchbase-2.7.0_amd64_vc11\include
```

but I have 54 errors like this:
exceptions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _imp__lcb_get_errtype
(same errors with the libcouchbase 2.6.4 version for VS 2015)

At this point my best option is trying to use the Windows installer (that should include the C SDK itself) for Python 3.4, but the installer check for the Python 3.4 version.
**How can I force the installer for Python 3.4 to run on my Python 3.6?**

Comment: Most code which works on python3.4 _should_ work on python3.5 too.  It's likely that a bug was introduced in the `couchbase-python-client` since you last installed it for python3.4.  This would also explain the "[build|failing]" that you see.  If possible, you should see what version of the couchbase client you have working in python3.4 and then try to install that version specifically using `pip`... (`pip install couchbase==<version>`)

Comment: Also MongoDB has only driver for Python 3.4 but `pip install pymongo` (on Python 3.6) works fine.  
Probably that version of Couchabse Python SDK is really not working.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) with the right Python version that you want to use. This will let you have a project using an older version of Python even though you have multiple versions installed on your system. I believe you can create the virtualenv using the `-p` flag to specify the version of Python that you want to use. Once you are in that virtualenv, you can `pip install` your dependencies with no issue.

Something that will make virtualenv a bit more usable for you will be [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper/), so check that out too if you have the time (although I don't know if it works on Windows.)

Comment: Is it possible to avoid this trouble? I don't mind virtualenv, but I don't want to move my whole project 2 version back (which risk incompatibility) just to be able to connect to Python Couchbase... Is there any other way?

Comment: You could write a separate python 3.4 program which you can shell out to in order to make your couchbase queries. If I was in your position, though, I'd either port the client to 3.6 or stop using one of couchbase or python for my project.